# is there any way to send asynchronous data to client through template engine?

Tags: node.js, express, asynchronous, pug, template-engine

Is there any way to send response to client through pug in express with rendering the view 2 times for a single page, or is there any way to send asynchronous data to client through template engine?

Below is my code in which response is send directly as HTML content and i want to replace it with **pug**. now the problem is **response.write()** will be happening first and **res.end()** will be executing after the promise resolving and i want to send response to client in the same order of execution 1 after another not by as all at once because both the event has time gap.
any help can i get here?

```
console.log('File saved to', filename);
            response.write('File downloaded to Server in DIR: '+filename+"<br>");
            promiseCounter++;
            if (promiseCounter == 15) {
                afterDownloading();
            }
          }).catch((err) => {
            afterDownloading();
            throw err;
          });
    }

}

function afterDownloading()
{
    var hrefString = "<br><a href='http://localhost:3000/displayKeywords'>Click here</a> to see all the keywords"+
                    "  Entered yet!<br>";
    response.end("Downloading Completed"+hrefString);
    console.log("Downloading Completed!");

    mongo.insert(fileDetail);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

A better approach to what you want to achieve is to update the UI through ajax. You can follow these steps for this:

1. Render your page normally
2. Trigger an ajax request on this page's load. This ajax request will perform the asynchronous operation and get back the data that is required to update the UI.
3. Update the UI when your ajax request gets response.

Comment: i didn't get the point.
its about the rendering of the template engine.
if I am sending the request through Ajax asynchronously still I have to render my pug page which is a single page, how can I render that page asynchronously having different data of the page for different request?

Comment: @user8929168 first you render the single page using pug. Then for each piece of information that you want to be added to that page, you fire a separate ajax request. These ajax requests get their respective data from server in json/html or whichever form and then you can update your html page and append this new info in that.